# Filter an array of dictionaries that all must contain all of specified values

Tags: elasticsearch

Say I had this document:

```
         {
        "_index": "food",
        "_type": "recipes",
        "_id": "AU2LjsMLOuShTUj_LBrT",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
           "name": "granola bars",
           "ingredients": [
              {
                 "name": "butter",
                 "quantity": 4
              },
              {
                 "name": "granola",
                 "quantity": 6
              }
              ]
           }
        }
```

Using the following filter matches this document fine:

```
POST /food/recipes/_search
{
"query": {
    "filtered": {
        "query": {
            "match_all": { }
        },
        "filter": {
            "nested": {
                "path": "ingredients",
                "filter": {
                    "bool": {
                        "must": [
                            {
                                "terms": {
                                    "ingredients.name": [
                                        "butter",
                                        "granola"
                                    ]
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

However it will also match documents that have additional ingredients.
How can I query so that it will only match documents that only have the ingredients butter and granola?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a "double negative", so to speak. You want to match parent documents that have nested docs that match your query, and no nested documents that don't match your query.

To test I set up the following index:

```
PUT /test_index
{
   "settings": {
      "number_of_shards": 1
   },
   "mappings": {
      "doc": {
         "properties": {
            "ingredients": {
               "type": "nested",
               "properties": {
                  "name": {
                     "type": "string"
                  },
                  "quantity": {
                     "type": "long"
                  }
               }
            },
            "name": {
               "type": "string"
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

And added these two documents:

```
PUT /test_index/doc/1
{
   "name": "granola bars",
   "ingredients": [
      {
         "name": "butter",
         "quantity": 4
      },
      {
         "name": "granola",
         "quantity": 6
      }
   ]
}

PUT /test_index/doc/2
{
   "name": "granola cookies",
   "ingredients": [
      {
         "name": "butter",
         "quantity": 5
      },
      {
         "name": "granola",
         "quantity": 7
      },
      {
         "name": "milk",
         "quantity": 2
      },
      {
         "name": "sugar",
         "quantity": 7
      }
   ]
}
```

Your query returns both the documents. For the purposes of this question, to make it easier to understand, I first simplified your query a little:

```
POST /test_index/doc/_search
{
   "query": {
      "filtered": {
         "query": {
            "match_all": {}
         },
         "filter": {
            "nested": {
               "path": "ingredients",
               "filter": {
                  "terms": {
                     "ingredients.name": [
                        "butter",
                        "granola"
                     ]
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Then I added an outer `"bool"` with two `"nested"` filters. One is the filter you originally had inside a `"must"`, and the second is the opposite of the filter you had (so it will match nested documents that do NOT contain those terms), inside a `"must_not"`:

```
POST /test_index/doc/_search
{
   "query": {
      "filtered": {
         "query": {
            "match_all": {}
         },
         "filter": {
            "bool": {
               "must": [
                  {
                     "nested": {
                        "path": "ingredients",
                        "filter": {
                           "terms": {
                              "ingredients.name": [
                                 "butter",
                                 "granola"
                              ]
                           }
                        }
                     }
                  }
               ],
               "must_not": [
                  {
                     "nested": {
                        "path": "ingredients",
                        "filter": {
                           "not": {
                              "filter": {
                                 "terms": {
                                    "ingredients.name": [
                                       "butter",
                                       "granola"
                                    ]
                                 }
                              }
                           }
                        }
                     }
                  }
               ]
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

This returns only the one doc:

```
{
   "took": 1,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 1,
      "successful": 1,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 1,
      "max_score": 1,
      "hits": [
         {
            "_index": "test_index",
            "_type": "doc",
            "_id": "1",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
               "name": "granola bars",
               "ingredients": [
                  {
                     "name": "butter",
                     "quantity": 4
                  },
                  {
                     "name": "granola",
                     "quantity": 6
                  }
               ]
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

Here is all the code I used for testing it:

http://sense.qbox.io/gist/e5fd0c35070fb329d40ad342b3198695e6f52d3a